# Compute determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have to compute the following determinant of an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix

$$\Delta_{n+1} :=\begin{vmatrix} 
1 & 1 &  \dots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 &  \dots & 1 & x_1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 &  \dots & x_2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\vdots\ & \vdots\ & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ 
x_n & 1 &  \dots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$

If I subtract the first row from all the other rows, I easily get that

$$\Delta_{n+1} = (-1)^{n+2}(x_1-1)(x_2-1)\cdots(x_n-1)$$

by using Laplace expansion on the last column. However, the answer given in my book is:

$$\Delta_{n+1} = (-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}(x_1-1)(x_2-1)\cdots(x_n-1)$$

I wonder which one is correct. I tried computing

$$(n+2) - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

to prove that this number is always even but that doesn't seem true. So, what is the real answer here?

Comment: You know that $(-1)^{n+2}=(-1)^n$, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, I do :) But why do $(n+2)$ and $n(n+1)/2$ have the same parity ?! It seems to me they don't. If so, one of the two answers must be incorrect.

Comment: They *don't* have the same parity in general. I just thought that it was strange that you wrote $(-1)^{n+2}$ when you could have just written $(-1)^n$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh, OK... Yes, I just wanted to underline the fact that when I use Laplace expansion it's on the last column and the only non-zero element (in the sum) comes from $a_{1,n+1}$.

Comment: The results are different for n=2, so one of them must be wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake!!! It's very basic. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

We have\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\1&x_1&1\\x_2&1&1\end{vmatrix}&=\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\0&x_1-1&0\\x_2-1&0&0\end{vmatrix}\\&=\begin{vmatrix}0&x_1-1\\x_2-1&0\end{vmatrix}\\&=-(x_1-1)(x_2-1).\end{align}As you can see, the sign is negative here. So, in this case, your book is correct, but you are not.